# Less CSS trickery for hover and multiple fonts on button with round edges

Tags: javafx-2

**Goal:** Create a round button that has multiple text fonts.

**Example:** See RoundButtonWithMultipleFonts.java and RoundButtonWithMultipleFonts.css

*RoundButtonWithMultipleFonts.java:*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RoundButtonWithMultipleFonts extends Application {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Button with multiple fonts?");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(getRoot(), 400, 400));
    stage.getScene().getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("RoundButtonWithMultipleFonts.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
  }

  private Parent getRoot() {
    Button button = new Button(""); // The labels should be the buttons text
    button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button clicked");
      }
    });

    Label header = new Label("A Prideful Header"); // Label for big font on button
    header.getStyleClass().addAll("header");

    Label footer = new Label("a humble footer"); // Label for small font on button
    footer.getStyleClass().addAll("footer");

    // Since the labels are on top of the button, pass any events they capture to the button
    configurePassThroughEvents(button, header, footer);

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.getChildren().addAll(button, header, footer);

    return stack;
  }

  private void configurePassThroughEvents(Control targetControl, Control... sourceControls) {
    MouseEventPassThrough passThroughEvent = new MouseEventPassThrough(targetControl);
    for(Control sourceControl : sourceControls) {
      sourceControl.setOnMouseClicked(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseDragged(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseDragEntered(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseDragExited(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseDragOver(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseDragReleased(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseEntered(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseExited(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseMoved(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMousePressed(passThroughEvent);
      sourceControl.setOnMouseReleased(passThroughEvent);
    }
  }

  private static class MouseEventPassThrough implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
    private final Control targetControl;
    private MouseEventPassThrough(Control targetControl) { this.targetControl = targetControl; }
    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) { targetControl.fireEvent(mouseEvent); }
  }
}
```

*RoundButtonWithMultipleFonts.css:*

```
.button {
  -fx-border-width: 1px;
  -fx-border-color: #000000;
  -fx-border-radius: 45;
  -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  -fx-background-radius: 45;
  -fx-padding: 50 100;
}
.button:hover {
  -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, coral 100%);
}

.label {
  -fx-padding: 10;
  -fx-background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.header {
  -fx-font-size: 110%;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-translate-y: -20;
}

.footer {
  -fx-font-size: 80%;
  -fx-translate-y: 20;
}
```

*Runtime Results:*

[image: Mouse is over the corner of the button but not inside the buttons visual boundary. The button is showing as if the mouse is hovering over it, but the mouse is not over the visual boundary of the button as specified by the css border and background properties.]

**Problem:**

1. When the mouse scrolls over one of the button's corners, the button enters the hovered state, but the mouse is still outside the visual bounds of the button indicated by the button's border and background. (See image.)
2. This example uses a stack pane, multiple labels, an event pass through mechanism, and css trickery to give the appearance of a button containing text with multiple fonts.

**Questions:**

1. How can I specify that the button should enter the hovered state only if the mouse collides with the buttons visual boundary as specified in the css with the border or background properties?
2. Is there a simpler way to specify multiple fonts (with general text layout) for a button than what is done in this example? Ideally I would want to just use a Button with a nested Node as the text. That would allow me to put anything I wanted inside the buttons textual area without needing the event pass through mechanism, the StackPane, and the css trickery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setGraphic(Node node);` method of `Button` class to set your custom labels on button. Here is an example,

```
Label header = new Label("A Prideful Header");
header.getStyleClass().addAll("header");

Label footer = new Label("a humble footer");
footer.getStyleClass().addAll("footer");


VBox box = new VBox();
box.getChildren().addAll(header,footer);

Button button = new Button();
button.setGraphic(box);
```

Comment: +1 for answering how to remove the need for the StackPane, event passthrough mechanism, and some of the css trickery. 

I'm still looking for an answer to make the button only enter the hovered state when the mouse enters the visual boundaries as specified by either the background or border css properties. If you can edit your answer to include the solution for that problem I'll select this as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @axiopisty, I guess there is no solution for your round button, reason: though it shows a rounded button it occupies/covers the same whole space. Why don't you use image instead of using button?